# How asynchronous programming would work without direct memory access (DMA)?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, dma

To my understanding async programming involves no threads.

According to my **understanding** of [Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) article, it simply gains its performance by utilizing DMA engine in the hardware.
It works as follow:

1. Async Task initiates DMA engine to copy data from memory buffer to an I/O device.
2. The tasks returns and relinquish control to the synchronizer - or whatever its called - to allow another task to run.
3. When the DMA finishes, it notifies the operating system with and interrupt.
4. Then somehow the operating system notifies the synchronizer that the operation is done.
5. Finally the synchronizer runs the rest of the code in the Async task.

This is implemented in `C#` via a state machine, a simple example [here](https://sharplab.io/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoUlaIoYB0AKgBYBOqAhgCb5k0gDWIO2ADsAEYA2YAMYxBfZiBgBhGAG9sMBTG78hMAG4B7MHRgBZABQBKWfMUBfUwstLeA4cwQRhm7TB7BkyDRACMAfUk7Fn0NHgArVEFkGBBUCDpUSgAaGABRNTjkAEFKKAlUQ2s5RRKpbxANPlRiAHVKMDQAGUhUfQAiHlQAMw1qGBoAdxoG/DbDHFLFQeHogHFUZDgNdAXyfCyQR0EjCcmyiAqq2vqmlvaaLrRKfqGR6DHdhQsS62U7GFJmFhh5xeXV9abJxGIrWErUZDASgQD5fYgAEVQYgQ+gATAAGTHjawWMxAA=) ( Credits goes to [Lasse V. Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v-karlsen)

---

To my knowledge IF DMA is not available, then Programmed I/O will be used involving the CPU in the data copy operation. Is there alternatives to DMA other than PI/O ?

How async-await gains performance in this case ? To my understanding I just see it adds more over-head ( the state-machine and the context switching of interrupts ) with zero gain.

To what extend my understanding is right ?

PS: I don't use C# at all - but I found the example really helpful -, I am okay with any example in any language.

Comment: The *async and await pattern* is not about performance, its about scalability, and although DMA would be an afforded efficiency its not what makes it scalable.

Comment: So there maybe no gains, but it's utilized to write more modular code ?

Comment: It depends what you are calling gains and performance, with the *async and await pattern* its likely not what you have in your mind as performant. If being able to scale to twice the amount of concurrent requests on a webserver is what you call a gain, then great. However on a per call basis, its usually slower, as it needs to negotiation more code and has more internal mechanics to achieve its task (term use loosely)

Comment: I can't see where Cleary says "it simply gains its performance by utilizing DMA engine in the hardware". Is that your interpretation?

Comment: Oh I see, it's right now a throughput vs per call performance. 
I've not been considering a webserver example, I can easily grasp the throughput gain  in async-wait pattern with DMA, as the thread will do CPU bound tasks to serve other requests. But if the CPU is involved in each I/O transaction I can see no throughput gain and maybe a thread pool may be a better solution. A thread for each request or a thread to serve the I/O aspect .

Comment: @Enigmativity, yes this is mine, I will update the question to clarify this right now.

Comment: I think you're conflating the idea that `async`/`await` relies on DMA for a performance improvement. I think they are both at a different level of abstraction. I don't think that `async`/`await` has any awareness that DMA is being used under the hood. I think it's a bit like saying that motor vehicles rely on the chemical reaction of burning fuel so to be a better mechanic you should learn chemistry.

Comment: Whether the CPU polls or not there are still limitations and performance problems when blocking threads in the framework, whether you can overcome those by carefully programming at the framework level to out perform what would be done in the kernel and HAL architecture is an open question to me. Why not get a device where you can disable DMA somehow and run some async and await non DMA enabled benchmarks and let us know?

Comment: All dogs are mammals, but not all mammals are dogs... Async await code *may* be waiting for I/O. I/O *might* be implemented using OS completion ports to resume processing. The OS *may* be using DMA to complete that I/O. async / await does mean that you don't need one thread per `Task`, and that the language must re-implement the equivalent of CPU thread state for paused `Task`s.